# Can't find component with JNDI name - org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage

Tags: components, ejb, jndi, naming

I'm trying to access my EJBs with their full names. The name is a `String` :

```
private final String ejbJndiLocation = "java:global/" + app
        + ".ear/myApp-ejb.jar/MyEjbModule!com.ejb.service.impl.MyEjbModule";
```

This is the exact name when I go through the installed applications on WAS. Though, when I access it with :

```
context = new InitialContext();
MyEjbModule = (MyEjbLocal) context.lookup(ejbJndiLocation);
```

I get the following exception :

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: MC41367Node01Cell/applications, name: myApp.ear/myApp.ear/myApp-ejb.jar/MyEjbModule!com.ejb.service.impl.MyEjbModule: First component in name myApp.ear/myApp.ear/myApp-ejb.jar/MyEjbModule!com.ejb.service.impl.MyEjbModule not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4564)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1822)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1777)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1434)
>       ...
>       Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.handleNameNotFound(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:2534)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.getNextWsnOptimizedNamingContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1277)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4670)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4665)

Is there a way to find out the full name on the server? I really need to access it with the full name.

Technologies: `Java6`, `EJB 3.1`, `Websphere Server 8.5`

Comment: The lookup name was incorrect. The right name to lookup for is : java:global/"+app+"/myApp-ejb/MyEjbModule!com.ejb.service.MyEJBLocal